# Conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range using sp_send_dbmail

Tags: sql, sql-server

First, please bear with me as I still have a lot to learn and I am very open to suggestions if there is a better way of doing this.

A business unit needs a scheduled job that executes a stored proc that returns certain data. They want this put into a csv file and emailed to certain users. The job will run after the first of the month and the stored proc needs the parameter of the last business day of the previous month. Here is the code I have:

```
declare @query varchar(8000)

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
@profile_name='Profile',
@recipients='steve@mycompany.com',
@subject='Portfolio Report',
--@body='See attached report',

@query = '
SET DATEFIRST 1;
DECLARE @LastBusinessDay DATE
DECLARE @LastMonth DATE
SELECT @LastMonth = EOMONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE()))
SET @LastBusinessDay = convert(DATE, dateadd(day, -(SELECT max(dayCount) 
    from (values (DATEPART(WEEKDAY, EOMONTH(@LastMonth)) - 5),
    (0 )) as allDays(dayCount)), EOMONTH(@LastMonth)), 112)

EXEC dbname..sp_create_report @LastBusinessDay,0
',

@attach_query_result_as_file=1,
@query_attachment_filename = 'PortfolioReport.csv',
@query_result_separator = ',',
```

I can get the query to return the correct date and data but when I include it in the code to send the email, I get the following error

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. Please let me know if I need to include something else. If I need to scrap this and go another route, I'm not particularly attached to this method.

Comment: None of that code appears to generate an error. I would suggest the problem is in your SP `dbname..sp_create_report`. We need to definition for that.

Comment: I was afraid of something like that. The sp was developed by the business and getting those things changed is a big hassle. Thanks for your input.

Comment: Did you by any chance mean to make `@LastBusinessDay` a `VARCHAR`? That would explain the `112` in the `CONVERT`, and might also explain the error if the stored procedure actually expects a `VARCHAR` rather than a `DATE` (which it then further converts internally). Either that or the `112` is just superfluous, as it's not currently doing anything.

Comment: Nice spot @JeroenMostert. If that is the case, and the OP is using a language that treats dates in the format `yyyy-dd-MM` they could well have an error. Casting a `date` to a `varchar` would result in the format `yyyy-MM-dd`; today that would be `'2018-11-27'`.  There aren't 27 months in the year, so it would generate the error seen. Of course, that creates the question: Why is an SP that is wanting a date value expecting a `varchar` and not a `date`?

Comment: @Larnu: hey, don't forget that `DATE` as a type is a mere 10 years old. There's still plenty of code and tables out there that think `CHAR(8)` or even `INT` are the perfect type for dates.

Comment: True, @JeroenMostert but then every version of SQL Server that doesn't have access to the `date`datatype is now (well) out of support. Certainly, however, `datetime` has been around for far longer than 10 years, so that could have been used. Yes, things have been improved in data types on SQL Server, however, that doesn't explain why after 10+ years the applications haven't either. :)

Comment: Some food for thought... https://sqlperformance.com/2014/09/system-configuration/stop-making-sql-server-dirty-work

Comment: Thanks all of you for your input. I learned a thing or 2 here. I did scrap it and went with a PowerShell script that worked like a charm right off. Not sure why I didn't go that route to begin with but hey, it's working! Thanks again!